# .desktop file running bash terminal command for wine app

Tags: command-line, bash, wine, .desktop

The following works :

```
WINEPREFIX="/media/t/e9f70369-a3af-4c6e-b2cf-57ade77c38de/WINE" wine '/media/t/e9f70369-a3af-4c6e-b2cf-57ade77c38de/WINE/drive_c/Program Files/Forged Alliance Forever/FAForever.exe'
```

the following .desktop file does not :

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "WINEPREFIX='/media/t/e9f70369-a3af-4c6e-b2cf-57ade77c38de/WINE' wine '/media/t/e9f70369-a3af-4c6e-b2cf-57ade77c38de/WINE/drive_c/Program Files/Forged Alliance Forever/FAForever.exe'"
Name=FAF
Comment=Forged Alliance Forever
Icon=/home/t/.local/share/icons/stremio.png
```

[image]

why?

Comment: Try removing`gnome-terminal -e ` from the `exec`. And make sure that you have got the name of that drive correct. If that was the problem, I would rename it to something more meaningful.

Comment: the name of the drive was gotten from drag and dropping to terminal so it's exact plus if it wasn't exact the terminal only version wouldn't work. I control-shift-C 'ed the command so it is the same in the .desktop file and without the `gnome-terminal -e` I get a window that says : "There was an error launching the application"